# Getting WPF DataGrid selection direction

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm using SelectionMode as Extended (multi select) with WPF DataGrid.
The SelectedIndex value always returns the first row that was selected, irrespective of the selection direction.

For example, if I start at index 0 and end at 4, I can work with it fine. But if I start from 4 and go to 0, SelectedIndex returns 4 and I don't have a clue to add the number of selected cells or subtract.

Is there a way to find the selection direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to know which items in a [Datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) are selected when using multiselection is to iterate through the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.selecteditems.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I require the item's row# in the datagrid. Is there a way that I can extract the row# from that? Or at least, check if it is selected? I can't find a row number or IsSelected property for an item (using VB.NET here)

Comment: You could use a linq expression to find the index of all the Items which are also in the SelectedItems collection. But I don't get why you would want the rownumer having the actual items.